# Show that definition 2.6 is equivalent to the following slight modification:

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

We write $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = L$ provided that for every positive integer $m$ there is a real number $N$ so that $|s_n-L<1/m$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Definition 2.6: 
Let ${s_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We
say that $s_n$ converges to a number $L$ and write
$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}s_n=L$
or
$s_n \rightarrow L \ as\  n \rightarrow \infty$
provided that for every number $\epsilon$> 0 there is an integer $N$ so that
$|s_n - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$.

To show equivalency, can we just say $1/m = \epsilon$ since we can make $\epsilon$ sufficiently small? It can't be that simple.

Comment: Setting $\varepsilon=1/m$ proves only one of the two directions of the equivalence. Do you have the "Archmedean property" an an explicit axiom for your real numbers? If you do, you're probably supposed to use that to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find an $m$ such that $1/m\le\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you, that helped make the connection!